# DGRAPH Log report DocumentCollectionCategories::GetDocumentScore invalid parameter

Tags: endeca

I'm looking at our Dgraph.log file and I'm seeing a lot of the following errors.  Can anybody point me towards the cause of it? I've verified that my property "p_sort_default" exists and is being populated with data.  I'm not sure how to track down where it's being used as a parameter incorrectly.

```
ERROR   01/02/14 06:02:50.414 UTC   DGRAPH  {dgraph}: DocumentCollectionCategories::GetDocumentScore invalid parameter "p_sort_default".
```

Comment: Are you using any relevance ranking strategies?

Comment: Yes and that parameter is used a static module in the relevance ranking.  Any idea why it would flag it as "invalid"?

Comment: What is the property type of "p_sort_default" and can you provide some test data for it.

Comment: It's type is integer.  Examples would be -1, -42, -13, 2, 4.  We've been using this Search Interface for years not sure if I've just missed these errors or they're new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to using a search interface with a dimension search.  The search interface was designed to be used with a navigation query which have the parameter "p_sort_default".  The dimensions do not have the parameter and are throwing the error.  We are setting up a new search interface specific for the dimension search to use to clear up the error.